# In jQuery, can I store elements using .data() onto another element for fast retrieval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

**Can I use the *data()* function to store a dom element (or a jQuery element) onto another element? (see code below)**

**Does it store it by value or by reference? Is it good practice?**

I want to be able to quickly and easily find the slave element (see code below) of a master element, like so:

```
$slave = $('.some .path .to .slave');
$master = $('.some .path .to .master');    
$master.data('slave', $slave);    
$master.click(function (){ $(this).data('slave').toggle() });
```

(obviously the code is stupid, but I'm actually looping through a lot of master and slave elements.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store whatever you want, whether or not you should.

JS variables are references to objects, no? (That's only partially rhetorical–what else would a DOM query return other than a reference? A deep copy?)

Comment: I would guess neither a reference nor a deep copy of the DOM, but a jQuery object which has a bunch of stuff and maybe some references to DOM objects.

Comment: (What's a variable that references a jQuery object if not a reference?)

Comment: yeah but keeping a reference to an object would keep the whole jquery object in scope wouldn't it? it's not just a reference to a dom node which would already exist i would guess.

Comment: Yep, it would, if course (hence the "whether or not you should" comment in the answer, and Law's suggestion to keep just the selector.

Comment: What about storing the dom element instead? `$master.data('slave', $slave[0]);` Would it store the reference?

Comment: Already said you could, and yes-what else could it store? Still not convinced it's a good idea from a memory management standpoint, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: But if it stores a reference to a DOM element, it shoudn't take that much memory. Would it?

Comment: In your code, slave isn't a DOM element, it's a jQuery object. I don't know what the memory usage is, you'd need to test.

Comment: I found this thread because of an issue I had with a colorpicker that didn't reference the calling object on change (on open only).  I have a page that uses around 50 of the same colorpicker, so I used this method to store a reference to the dom element in the colorpicker as it's opened.  It worked great for me.  Since  it worked for me, I'm giving your first upvote (strange that it's accepted and no upvotes)

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do this:

```
var slavePath=$('.some .path .to .slave');
var master=$('.some .path .to .master').data('slave', slavePath);
master.click(function(){ $($this.data('slave')).toggle()});
```

Just store the selector to the slave, not the whole object.

Comment: You probably got an error in your code, slavePath contains a list of elements in your case.